# Is there a way to test AZ Cli scripts

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-cli

While developing AZ CLI scripts I wonder if there is a way to test or somehow get a preview of the different configurations to be applied by the script before they are actually applied to the infrastructure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can validate only the deployment template not any CLI commands. However , you can leverage [Az Next](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-tools/az-next-ai-powered-interactive-assistant/ba-p/2118582) is the first CLI recommender to provide contextual command recommendations based on the analysis of user behavior and session context

Answer (score 0):

There is no dry run option in Azure CLI.

Azure CLI allows you to configure and manage Azure from Bash, PowerShell, or a Command Prompt window. Azure CLI supports command reuse, both on an ad-hoc basis and through scripts. You'll need to be aware of the capabilities of the shell that you run.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/use-cli-effectively